# Quantum mechanical model of benzene ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, molecules, quantum-chemistry

The infinite square well scenario can be used to model the $\pi$-electrons of a benzene ring. It can be shown that the eigenfunctions of the ring can be written as

$\Psi_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{\frac{i2n\pi}{L}x} , (n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2...)$

when the condition $\Psi(x) = \Psi(x+L)$ is taken into consideration. This is all good.

But then it can also be shown that the eigenfunctions for the three lowest energy states can be written as

$\psi_{0} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$

$\psi_{1} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\cos(\frac{2\pi x}{L})$

$\psi_{2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{2\pi x}{L})$

The first one is fine but $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$ I don't understand. I think that I am supposed to be using the fact that all solutions are linear combinations of other known solutions. Does anyone know how to show this?

Comment: Note that the first excited level is two-fold degenerate $n=\pm 1$. You should be able to show that any linear combination of $\Psi_{n=1}$ and $\Psi_{n=-1}$ is still an energy eigenstate with exactly the same energy, and among those the real ones are your $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hamiltonian operator for an electron in this model is
$$H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$
where $m$ is the electron mass.
So you have Schrödinger's equation
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Psi(x)=E\Psi(x) \tag{1}$$
and the periodic condition $$\Psi(x)=\Psi(x+L). \tag{2}$$

The solutions of (1) and (2) are the normalized wave functions
$$\Psi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{i2\pi nx/L} \text{  , with }n=0,\pm 1, \pm 2, ...$$
with energies
$$E_n=\frac{2\pi^2\hbar^2}{mL^2}n^2$$

Here you see, the solutions for $n$ and $-n$ have the same energy:
$$E_n=E_{-n}$$

Because of this, not only $\Psi_n(x)$ and $\Psi_{-n}(x)$ are solutions.
Also any linear combination
$$a\Psi_n(x)+b\Psi_{-n}(x)$$
is a solution for the same energy $E_n$ as well.
(You can easily verify this by checking Schrödinger's equation (1)
and the periodic condition (2).)
In order to get a normalized wave function again,
you need to choose constants satisfying $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. I am still unsure how to exactly get for instance 

$$ \psi_{1} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}cos(\frac{2\pi x}{L}) $$ ?

If I use for instance n=1 I get that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}(cos(\frac{2\pi x}{L}) + isin(\frac{2\pi x}{L}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}(cos(\frac{2\pi x}{L}) - isin(\frac{2\pi x}{L}) =\frac{2}{\sqrt{L}}cos(\frac{2\pi x}{L})  $$

I am missing something about the linear constants a and b I guess or doing something else wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @EodEnaj You almost got it. Use $a=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1/\sqrt{2}$ to get $a\Psi_1(x)+b\Psi_{-1}(x)=\sqrt{2/L}\cos(2\pi x/L)$.
Likewise, use $a=-i/\sqrt{2}$ and $b=i/\sqrt{2}$ you get the $\sin$ solution.